# Gtk#: change font size for Button

Tags: gtk#

I use Markup for change `Gtk.Label` font size. For example

```
label1.Markup="<span size='38000'>big text</span>";
```

How can I do it for Gtk.Button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var label = new Label();
label.Markup = "<span size='38000'>big text</span>";
var button = new Button(label);
```